# PrimeFaces two fileUpload controls run in conflict

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with two fileUpload controls:

```
<h:panelGroup id="distinctAttachmentsPanel" rendered="#{multipleSendingController.selectedAttachmentList == 2}">
<h:outputText value="Allegati distinti" />
  <p:fileUpload id="distinctFileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{multipleSendingController.onDistinctFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced"
    multiple="true"
    sizeLimit="100000000"
    label="Sfoglia"
    uploadLabel="Carica"
    cancelLabel="Annulla"
    update=":form:uploadedDistinctFiles" />
  <p:selectManyCheckbox id="uploadedDistinctFiles" value="#{multipleSendingController.selectedDistinctAttachments}" converter="#{multipleSendingController.fileConverter}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{multipleSendingController.distinctAttachments}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.name}" itemValue="#{a}" />  
  </p:selectManyCheckbox>
  <h:outputText value="File excel" />
  <p:fileUpload id="excelFileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{multipleSendingController.onExcelFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced"
    multiple="true"
    sizeLimit="100000000"
    label="Sfoglia"
    uploadLabel="Carica"
    cancelLabel="Annulla"
    update=":form:uploadedExcelFiles" />
  <p:selectManyCheckbox id="uploadedExcelFiles" value="#{multipleSendingController.selectedExcelFiles}" converter="#{multipleSendingController.fileConverter}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{multipleSendingController.excelFiles}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.name}" itemValue="#{a}" />  
  </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:panelGroup>
```

When I select one or more files into one of the fileUpload controls, the same files appear in the other control like it was selected even there.
I can't figure out what is appening.

Answer (score 0):

you should put each fileUpload inside a separate h:form

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from @ktaria could solve the problem it is probably not the best solution.

In this case your "widgetVar" values are conflicting and you should use different ones.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31152786)